# Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom getting this error while creating a linear model

Tags: r

I am creating a linear model from a data frame in which column 6 depends on column 1 to 5. Although the code executes properly, when I print the summary of the linear model I get the following.

```
Call:
lm(formula = AAPL[, 6] ~ AAPL[, 1] + AAPL[, 2], data = AAPL[, 
    c(1, 2)], subset = 1)

Residuals:
ALL 1 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    8.104         NA      NA       NA
AAPL[, 1]         NA         NA      NA       NA
AAPL[, 2]         NA         NA      NA       NA

Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
```

The code I am using :-

```
lm <- lm(train[,6] ~ train[,2]+train[,3]+train[,4]+train[,5]+train[,1] , 1 , data=train)
```

**PS:** If I remove the part **data=train** then this works in terminal but not when executed from file.

The next line of code which is almost same except one parameter runs perfectly.The next line is:

```
lm2 <- lm(train[,6] ~ train[,2]+train[,3]+train[,4]+train[,5]+train[,1] , 5)
```

Comment: what is `subset=1` supposed to be achieving here ... ?  In your case, it's selecting only the **first** observation, which makes it unsurprising that you can't fit the model very well ...

Comment: I don't know, that is in the output for summary(lm).

Comment: OK, then, what do you intend the second argument (`1`) to be doing?

Comment: According to what I understand, it is the degree of the equation. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: you're wrong (how did you reach that conclusion ... ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** you are (unintentionally?) specifying that the model should use only the first observation.  Let's look at what's here ...

```
lm <- lm(train[,6] ~ train[,2]+train[,3]+train[,4]+train[,5]+train[,1] , 
  1 , data=train)
```

- the first argument is the formula (fine, although (1) it's clearer to use variable names rather than columns and (2) if you are using all the variables in the data set to predict with, you can use the shortcut `y ~ .` (where `y` is the name of the response variable)
- what does the second argument mean? R matches arguments by position and name. The second and third arguments to `lm()` (see `?lm`) are `data` and `subset`. Since you have specified `data` as the third argument, and haven't named the second argument, R will interpret the second argument as `subset`. Let's see what `?lm` says about the `subset` argument:

  > subset: an optional vector specifying a subset of observations to be
  >         used in the fitting process.

  That means that R will take the value `1` as a "vector specifying a subset of observations", i.e. it will take *only the first row of the training data set*.

  Since you are using only one observation to fit the data set, `lm()` can fit only an intercept, not any other parameters.

By the way, it's generally not recommended to use the names of built-in R functions (`lm`) as variable names. It works most of the time, but when it doesn't work the resulting error messages are very confusing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I am new to R, it was completely unintentional. I can now understand the error that was coming.